# Cordova iOS WKWebView workaround for Big canvas.toDataURL

Tags: javascript, cordova, canvas, wkwebview, cordova-ios

Using cordova-ios latest which has WKWebView Engine. In my app, I am making canvas of multiple image. Till generation of canvas works fine. It displays canvas too.

But canvas.toDataURL() is not giving output. Even code after that also not working.

I am trying to merging remote image to local image through canvas.

My trials:
CORS issue, I have already tried put anonymous wherever required.

Make small canvas, when I generate smaller canvas, toDataURL is perfectly working.

So is there any workaround please?

Answer (score 0):

It is because with WKWebView there is no access via `file://` which is probably used to load your tiles.

Install this plugin https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr

Then set your prefences to

```
 <preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
 <preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
```